# How do you find where roads intersect in an aerial image?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing

I just started and have been working on image processing for this last 2 months. I'm wondering if we can detect where roads intersect from a given aerial image view. I've tried it with my limited knowledge, and I didn't get what I wanted.

Here is my sample image:

[image]

Here is what I've managed to produce:

[image]

This is code that I have written to create circles and find where the lines intersect:

```
vector<Point2f> corners;
Point2f pt;

for (int i = 0; i < lines1.size()/14; i++)
{
    for (int j = i+1; j < lines1.size()/14; j++)
    {
        pt = computeIntersect(lines1[i], lines1[j]);

        if (pt.x >= 0 && pt.y >= 0) {
            corners.push_back(pt);
            circle(output, pt,10,CV_RGB(255,0,0),2);

        }
    }
}
```

The methods I'm using are the Canny edge detector followed by the Hough transform.  Are there any better techniques?  Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: My suggestion would be to hire a contractor that knows about image processing. The problem you've stated is, and this is a technical term, "really hard".

Comment: Can you also include your code for `computeIntersect`?  It's hard to diagnose where you're going wrong without all of your code.  FWIW, you seem to have detected the most prominent intersections in the image.

Comment: Is there a Computer Vision SO?

Comment: @a-Jays no there isn't. However there is a proposal on Area 51 but there hasn't been much activity to get it off the ground. As such, people have posted CV inquiries either on here or DSP StackExchange.

Comment: @rayryeng what do you mean by code for `computeIntersect`? i'm using opencv and `computeIntersect` is already there. so all i need is just call it.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't aware that the function was part of OpenCV. I've never seen it before.